# Mobile OTP function enabling

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have recently bought a extension for mobile otp, which had created its registration form where the mobile OTP function is working. please see the screenshot below.

[image]

Now apart from this I have 2 other forms for registering, which doesn't have this Mobile OTP verifying function. Please check the screenshot below

[image]

[image]

So I want to enable, Mobile OTP functionality in these 2 registration forms as well, so how can I do this. Please if anyone can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Please check for module settings,if there is any configuration to add otp registration for custom forms, if it is provided by module provider then just add it in configuration file, if it is not provided, you need to add via code, check how they added for existing form and add to the new forms.